# Django all auth microsoft graph profile picture

Tags: django, django-models, microsoft-graph-api, django-allauth

I use django-allauth about user registration/login using user's Microsoft Graph profile.  Now, I can take some standard information from Microsoft (default for all auth).  Is possible to retrieve also list of profile-pictures? How can make it in allAuth?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the profile photo of a user:

```
GET /me/photo/$value
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

AFAIK not sure we can fetch the list of profile photos, for more information please refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#to-retrieve-the-profile-photo-of-a-user

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually its showing error ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken

i can only my profile pic but can't access others.
is there any way to save others pics

Comment: These are the permissions requires to retrieve the profile photo of a user, can you please check this you have these permissions in token by decoding it in https://jwt.ms/:     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#to-retrieve-the-profile-photo-of-a-user